# Restricting a method to a subset of values of the caller's type parameter

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming

**Summary:** I want to add an instance method to instances of a parametrized type, but only for some values of the type parameter. Specifically, I have `List[E]`, but I only want instances of `List[List[_]]` to have a `flatten()` method.

---

I am learning the basics of Scala and functional programming by following along with the exercises in *Functional Programming in Scala* by Chiusano & Bjarnason.

Suppose I have a type `List[E]` and a companion object `List` that has methods for working with instances of `List[E]`.

```
sealed trait List[+E]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+E](head: E, tail: List[E]) extends List[E]

object List {
    def flatten[E](aListOfLists: List[List[E]]): List[E] = Nil
    def foldLeft[E, F](aList: List[E])(acc: F)(f: (F, E) ⇒ F): F = acc
}
```

Now suppose I want to create analogous methods on `List` instances that simply forward the calls to the companion object. I would try to augment the trait definition as follows.

```
sealed trait List[+E] {
    def foldLeft[F](acc: F)(f: (F, E) => F) = List.foldLeft(this)(acc)(f)
}
```

I run into a complication: `List.foldLeft()` works with any `List[E]`, but `List.flatten()` expects a `List[List[E]]` argument. Thus, I only want instances of `List[List[_]]` to have this method. How can I add `flatten()` to the appropriate subset of `List` instances? How do I use Scala's type system to express this restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can build up what we need piece by piece. First we know that we need a type parameter for our `flatten`, since we don't otherwise have a way to refer to the inner element type:

```
sealed trait List[+E] {
  def flatten[I] // ???
}
```

Next we need some way of establishing that our `E` is `List[I]`. We can't add constraints to `E` itself, since in many cases it won't be `List[I]` for any `I`, but we can require implicit evidence that this relationship must hold if we want to be able to call `flatten`:

```
sealed trait List[+E] {
  def flatten[I](implicit ev: E <:< List[I]) = ???
}
```

Note that for reasons related to variance (and type inference) we need to use `<:<` instead of `=:=`.

Next we can add the return type, which we know must be `List[I]`:

```
sealed trait List[+E] {
  def flatten[I](implicit ev: E <:< List[I]): List[I] = ???
}
```

Now we want to be able to call `List.flatten` on a `List[List[I]]`. Our `ev` allows us to convert values of type `E` into `List[I]`, but we don't have `E` values, we just have a `List[E]`. There are a number of ways you could fix this, but I'll just go ahead and define a `map` method and use that:

```
sealed trait List[+E] {
  def map[B](f: E => B): List[B] = this match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case Cons(h, t) => Cons(f(h), t.map(f))
  }

  def flatten[I](implicit ev: E <:< List[I]): List[I] = List.flatten(map(ev))
}
```

And then:

```
val l1 = Cons(1, Cons(2, Nil))
val l2 = Cons(3, Cons(4, Cons(5, Nil)))

val nested = Cons(l1, Cons(l2, Nil))
val flattened: List[Int] = nested.flatten
```

This won't actually work, since your `List.flatten` is broken, but it should when you fix it.

Comment: You have a nose for nosism. Instead of turning up mine, I will vote in that direction. Apparently SO disdains the traditional `$plus(1)`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you could use instances of `<:<` as functions;  `map(ev)` was the part I was missing.